# The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) is less than the minimum required for Xamarin.Forms (8.1)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

Está ocorrendo o seguinte erro ao compilar um app:

```
The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Representantes.Android (v8.0) is less than 
   the minimum required $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms (8.1). 
You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Representantes.Android.
Representantes.Android
```

Já instalei todas SDKs disponíveis, já tentei trocar nas propriedades todas as configs possíveis e não dá certo.

Também estou tendo problema porque nenhuma das referências estão sendo encontradas.

Answer (score 1):

Terá de alterar a Compile Version para 8.1, ou até 9.0

Na solução Android, Project Options -> Geral -> Compilar usando a versão: escolher a v9 ou v8.1 como é sugerido .

Depois, no Manifest.xml, alterar a target version também para 8.1 ou 9.0